# Crash app error while trying to deploy react-flask app on heroku

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, heroku

I'm currently getting this error when I run the heroku logs --tail command.

at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=digital-engagement-tool.herokuapp.com request_id=72b795df-278b-41f8-885c-71cad4b302f0 fwd="123.201.36.104" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2021-05-18T07:51:47.875518+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=digital-engagement-tool.herokuapp.com request_id=ddd95750-0437-41b2-89e8-973c709039f0 fwd="123.201.36.104" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

My Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn app:react-flask-app
```

I have named the app 'react-flask-app' because that's the name in my package.json file. Is that correct?

My api.py file:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='./build', static_url_path='/')
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='./build', static_url_path='/')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = Config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
app.config['MAIL_SERVER']= Config.MAIL_SERVER
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = Config.MAIL_PORT
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = Config.MAIL_USERNAME
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = Config.MAIL_PASSWORD
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = Config.MAIL_USE_SSL
mail = Mail(app)
db = flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy(app)


@app.route('/')
def index():
  return app.send_static_file('index.html')
```

----Other routes relevant to my application. Example:

```
 @app.route('/hcp-npi-name', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 def hcp_npi_name():
   engine = connect_pg()
   param = request.get_json()
   sql = "select a.* from dim_hcp_details a join dim_geography_table b on a.aligned_geography_id = 
      b.geography_id where b.user_id = " + str(param['user_id']) + " limit 1"
   print(sql)
   hcp_details = pd.read_sql_query(sql,engine)
   hcp_details['npi_hcp_concat'] = "[" + hcp_details['npi'] + "]" + hcp_details['first_name']
   hcp_dict = hcp_details.to_dict()
   return jsonify(hcp_dict)
```

And then:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(e):
   return app.send_static_file('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False, port=os.environ.get('PORT', 80))
```

After this, I also ran these commands in the terminal to create the heroku application.

```
 heroku create digital-engagement-tool
 heroku git:remote -a digital-engagement-tool
```

After that, I pushed this using the git push heroku master command.

I've used this link to deploy on heroku: [How to Deploy a React + Python Flask Project on Heroku](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-deploy-a-react-python-flask-project-on-heroku-edb99309311#:%7E:text=Installing%20gunicorn,your%20Flask%20application%20at%20Heroku.&text=Note%3A%20if%20you%20don%27t,have%20to%20install%20it%20first.&text=Run%20the%20command%20within%20the,in%20your%20project%20root%20folder.)

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I'm actually having the same issue right now. Any luck finding a solution?

Comment: I changed my Procfile from `web: gunicorn app:app` to `web: gunicorn app.app:app` The app.app is telling Heroku that my app.py file is in an app folder, so app/app.py. I now have a 404 error after deployment. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah, I had already figured it out. Thanks! You can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67585253/app-crash-error-on-trying-to-deploy-small-application-to-heroku