# App crash error on trying to deploy small application to Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I'm getting this error on deploying to heroku:

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=deploy-testv1.herokuapp.com 
request_id=b36172ff-cb1b-4436-978f-1be34e28a9e3 fwd="123.201.36.104" dyno= connect= service= 
status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-18T11:08:48.938254+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET 
path="/favicon.ico" host=deploy-testv1.herokuapp.com request_id=8e63e9a0-c621-47e0-a91d-bad7716ddde5 
fwd="123.201.36.104" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

My `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

Here is the `app.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse
from flask_cors import CORS 
from HelloApiHandler import HelloApiHandler

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='../build')
CORS(app) #comment this on deployment
api = Api(app)

@app.route("/", defaults={'path':''})
def serve(path):
   return send_from_directory(app.static_folder,'index.html')

api.add_resource(HelloApiHandler, '/flask/hello')
```

`HelloApiHandler.py` file:

```
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse

class HelloApiHandler(Resource):
def get(self):
 return {
  'resultStatus': 'SUCCESS',
  'message': "Hello Api Handler"
  }

def post(self):
print(self)
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('type', type=str)
parser.add_argument('message', type=str)

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args)
# note, the post req from frontend needs to match the strings here (e.g. 'type and 'message')

request_type = args['type']
request_json = args['message']
# ret_status, ret_msg = ReturnData(request_type, request_json)
# currently just returning the req straight
ret_status = request_type
ret_msg = request_json

if ret_msg:
  message = "Your Message Requested: {}".format(ret_msg)
else:
  message = "No Msg"

final_ret = {"status": "Success", "message": message}

return final_ret
```

My `App.js` file:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'

function App() {
  const [getMessage, setGetMessage] = useState({})

useEffect(()=>{
 axios.get('https://deploy-testv1.herokuapp.com/flask/hello').then(response => {
  console.log("SUCCESS", response)
  setGetMessage(response)
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error)
})

 }, [])
 return (
  <div className="App">
  <header className="App-header">
    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
    <p>React + Flask Tutorial</p>
    <div>{getMessage.status === 200 ? 
      <h3>{getMessage.data.message}</h3>
      :
      <h3>LOADING</h3>}</div>
  </header>
</div>
);
}

export default App;
```

My `root folder structure` view:

[image]

Inside `api folder`

[image]

I have provided everything that's needed. Please let me know what wrong am I doing? Is there something wrong in my procfile or in app.py/app.js? Or is my file structure incorrect?

Have also added nodejs and python buildpack in heroku.

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you have any questions or if there is code of some other file that you wish to see. This is a small test project so these are the main files.

Comment: What is the error message trying to tell you...?

Comment: I've added the error message in the question. It just says App crashed with code of H10. Don't know why app is crashing.

Comment: By the way I just copied requirements.txt file from my api folder and pasted inside my root folder. I hope that isn't a problem. I had just seen in 1 link where they kept requirements inside root folder.

Comment: It says a bit more than that, no? I can see that it includes a path... (do you know what favicon.ico is and why it is requested?)

Comment: It's a default error (even I don't know what it is) that it throws, if you check this website and scroll down, you'll see he got the same error: https://dev.to/lawrence_eagles/causes-of-heroku-h10-app-crashed-error-and-how-to-solve-them-3jnl#:~:text=A%20bug%20in%20your%20Procfile,your%20server%20is%20in%20server.&text=js%20this%20would%20definitely%20crash,App%20crashed%20error%20code%20message.

Comment: "I'm struggling" is a perfectly valid status update ;-)  It's important to not panic too much in these situations, and divide the problem into smaller steps (e.g. start with the simplest site you can deploy, then add features until you get stuck -- now you have a smaller problem you need to fix than you have now, rinse-and-repeat). Then the status update becomes "I'm struggling, I can deploy a site with x and y but not when I add z. I'm still making progress/I'm stuck and need some help."

Comment: Hi, Did you try to solve with this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43593542/python-flask-web-api-heroku-it-runs-locally-but-shows-application-error-when

Comment: Checking that, let's see if it works. I had tried that in my previous code (previous question), but will see in this one.

Comment: It's throwing the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `app.py`, this small change. Instead of just from HelloApiHandler, I changed it to api.HelloApiHandler. Apparently, while deploying on Heroku, we have to keep the Procfile as the reference even for Python files. It doesn't matter that the `app.py` file and `HelloApiHandler.py` file are in the same directory.

```
from api.HelloApiHandler import HelloApiHandler
```

And in Procfile. The same above reason

```
web: gunicorn api.app:app
```

This deployed my application.